# java web start unknown source exception

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, java-web-start

I have created a GUI in netbeans using java swing.  The main frame opens a DesktopPane with menu options where the user can choose to open internal frames within the main frame.  In order to run this GUI, I have to use 'Run file' in the mainframe.java file rather than use the green 'Run project' button.  I am new to netbeans and java web start but I followed the instructions on netbeans.org on how to configure the project to enable web start.  However, I get an error when I launch stating an 'unknown source' exception message.  I presume my error is caused by the fact that the GUI does not run from the 'run project' as stated above but I am not sure.  Can anyone advise me? Many thanks

Comment: Add more detail on exception message please